# jQuery datatables - connect subrows with sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am trying to do the following, I have a table with rows, some rows have rows below them wich can be collapsed. (see code below)

I am using the script: http://datatables.net to sort the table. But when I sort them the subrows always need to be on the same spot below the visibile one (grouped by their class or something)

How can this be done?

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>actions</td>     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="group-1">
      <td>Row visible</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="collapse">COLLAPSE SUBROWS</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="group-1" style="display: none;">
      <td>Row can be collapsed</td>
      <td>Row can be collapsed</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="group-2">
      <td>Row visibile 2</td>
      <td>Row visibile 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  var table = $('#table').DataTable();
</script>
```